# Saving the state of the typesetting engine

Tags: include

When editing a long document, it is tiring to recompile all of it. Usually you do not want a print-ready output, only a locally meaningful output, that you correctly entered formulae, your sentences are right and so on.

For that, a solution must start at saving the state of the TeX/LaTeX compiler into a file and reading it afterwards. Using this you could say you freeze your document up to a point and edit it only afterwards, let us say from a new page and generate only a few page of output, only to check basic things.

Is there a solution in this direction?

Comment: I am not sure what you are after. But are you aware of `\includeonlly` to include only a bit of a document (i.e. a chapter). You can also always comment stuff out that you don't need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a mechanism, you may include only parts of your document, the relevant commands are `\include{}`, `\input{}` and `\includeonly`. The difference has been explained here: [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/4736)

Answer (score 3):

(Note: editor-specific answer.)

Using Emacs + AUCTeX, this is [possible](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/auctex_25.html#Running-LaTeX-on-parts-of-your-document) (see also this [message](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2009-04/msg00100.html) -- which lists other possibilities I was unaware of).

Basically, if you mark a region, e.g., with `C-SPC` (= `M-x set-mark-command`; or `C-@`) to start the mark region, you can than partially compile the selected region via the command: `C-c C-r`.  This will compile only the selected region, relying on the preamble of the master file.  It can be useful if you quickly want to check something.

Answer (score 2):

This is a supplement to [Keks Dose's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201249/).

There are also packages you can use to manage parts of documents which are 'complete in themselves'. For example, diagrams and graphics often take a disproportionate time to compile so you don't want to re-compile them once you've got them right. Or you might want to be able to typeset a document as a chapter in a book or an independent article without maintaining separate versions.

Packages such as [standalone](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone), [docmute](http://ctan.org/pkg/docmute), [includex](http://ctan.org/pkg/includex) and [others](http://ctan.org/topic/subdocs) allow you to include the contents of complete documents, while maintaining the ability to compile those documents independently and/or to use pre-compiled versions of graphics etc. Some graphics packages such as [TiKZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) also offer a specialised option to 'externalise' graphics produced.